# Connection error from iPhone

Tags: ios

Recently I face the issue on my iphone like this:

[image]

translated to english: `Connection error from iPhone`, `call ended`

**When it happens?**

When I receive a call from other person on my iphone it is also displayed on my iPad. Now I try to answer the call from **iPad**. But then call is immediately ended and on both devices there is the same error.

> on iPhone: "Connection error from iPhone"
>
> on iPad: "Connection error from iPad"

So, why it happens?